# Is there a way to get all indices in cross cluster mode?

Tags: elasticsearch

I defined a remote clusters in my Elasticsearch environment (cluster_one,cluster_two) in this way:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster": {
      "remote": {
        "Verginia": {
          "seeds": [
            "SOME_IP:SOME_PORT"
          ]
        },
        "London": {
          "seeds": [
            "SOME_IP:SOME_PORT"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I succeed to run search queries, but I want to get more information about the remote clusters - which indices located in this clusters, how the indices mapped etc...
right now the only way I saw to do that is to get the remote information about the cross cluster ENV and get this information by rest directly to every cluster. 
My question is if there is build it mechanizem to get more information about cross cluster  ?